# Show 'Flag as spam' button instead of 'Close question' when handling spam flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam, offensive, flag-dashboard

When there is a pending spam flag, the new moderator flag dashboard shows two primary options in the bottom right: 'Delete question' and 'Close question ...'. While deleting the question is sometimes useful, closing the question is almost never the right cause of action. I'd rather have that replaced with a 'Flag question as spam' button. That action now takes an extra click (via the 'flag' link in the post).

[image]

Moderators on sites which don't see a lot of spam might not even know flagging spam is (often) better than deleting the post so that button would serve as a reminder as well.

The same idea can be applied to rude/abusive flags, and red flags on answers (IIRC only the 'Delete answer' button is shown, so there's certainly room for another button.)

Comment: While we're at it, can we get a "burn it to the ground" button in there, too, which would flag the post as spam and destroy the user who posted it?